# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I am getting this bug and I don't know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to animate this healthkit but for some reason it doesn't. I tested it by adding a debug.log and when I press Q I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't know why it would do this. Thanks for the help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Anim_Trigger_for_healthpack : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Coroutine onHealKit = null;
    private Animator anim;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            if (onHealKit == null)
                onHealKit = StartCoroutine(HealthKit());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HealthKit()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Qpress", true); //bug on this line
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        anim.SetBool("Qpress", false);
        onHealKit = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`anim` is never instantiated. Use `anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();` in `Start()` to get the reference when the scene begins.

Alternatively you can make it `public` and just drag and drop the `Animator` in the inspector.

Comment: ty I completely forgot about that